# Magento 2 Install via Composer error

Tags: magento2, installation

I am trying to install magento2 via composer using following command.
My System specification is **PHP Version 7.0.20-1~ubuntu16.04.1**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

I got the following error

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.7].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Comment: I also tried ref - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139634/magento-2-1-1-not-compatibile-with-php-7-1-0 but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Your error message already answered the question.

Magento 2 doesn't support PHP 7.1.x yet, please downgrade it to `~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6`
There is a typo in DevDocs, if you need to know about the detail, please check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8569).

Good luck and welcome to Magento 2 :)

Comment: I know that, but my PHP Version is 7.0.20-1 and this PHP version is in range of 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6

Comment: It said `your PHP version (7.1.6)`, please notice that PHP CLI might use different version with your PHP FPM. I have 4 PHP version in my webserver too.